# Why does KDE feel extremely slow on my PC?

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I've tried reading a lot about this issue but can not figure out why kde must be extremely slow, slower than windows on my PC. I use a laptop with 8th gen i5, 8gb ram and HDD(No SSD) and I am running kubuntu 22.04. I've tried other distros previously on the same machine (Ubuntu 22.04 with gnome) and it was fast wrt boot time and application launching (only counting apps not installed through snap). I didnt find it slow or laggy/sluggish in contrast to KDE. Mint (cinnamon) was insanely fast, literally the fastest I've used on my machine. KDE is significantly slow compared to both, and actually is sort of a hindrance when i work. I like KDE a lot and I think there's something wrong with my configuration which makes it seem that slow. I disabled Baloo, set power options to performance mode and there is no improvement. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "slow" mean? Are programs latent to start? Are windows slow to drag? Do animations drop frames? Being more specific will make it easier to suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: I am using Kubuntu and it is speed on both my older & now newer systems. While mostly about boot issues, some settings will make system faster. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Are you using snaps, they tend to be slow? Mint totally disables snaps, which I do in Kubuntu. But now Firefox is a snap & you have to manually install ppa  & change several settings to prevent reinstall of the snap.

Comment: make sure your hardware is working at full speed.  if you have nvidia graphics, you have to make sure the closed source driver is in use.  Also, you may want to try a different KDE distro as a test, like fedora kde spin.  I found this forum message for kubuntu and it isn't promising https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/u9mi5c/note_for_kubuntu_2204_lts_for_wayland

Comment: @ChrisDown Yea, programs are latent to start. The menu (which activates user Super key) lags as well, sometimes opens after 4-5 seconds. Takes too long to boot. There is however no problem with dragging windows, this is smooth. Searching for apps in the start menu lags almost always. The menu freezes after 2 keystrokes for about 2-3 seconds and continues.

Comment: I completely removed snaps and reinstalled firefox using the PPA. One of the first things I always do when I install Ubuntu 22.04. I will try implementing those settings and come back to you in a while. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @toppk How do I make sure the hardware is working at full speed? This specific machine does not have NVIDIA graphics, only Intel UHD. All I can think of is putting the power option to Performance mode, which I did.

Comment: @KeyShoe well these days things pretty much configure themselves for best performance, so I was pretty much talking about graphics drivers.    for the symptoms you describe I think it's just developers have been spoiled by SSD's and that is introducing a lot of latency.  booting a live usb distro would show you if it's worth investing in an upgrade to ssd.

Comment: @toppk Yeah it is probably the lack of SSD. But that doesnt explain why GNOME works fine although GNOME is considered heavier if not equal to KDE. Mint is however extremely smooth.

Comment: Pleas try Fedora 36.

Comment: @KeyShoe gnome-shell had a multiyear effort for gnome-shell to improve just app grid performance.  it was remarkably slow, but now not so bad.  i suppose that is a benefit that canonical and red hat use it as their default for paying customers.

Comment: While my desktop has SSD, my very old 2006 laptop with 1.5GB RAM & 5400rpm HDD ran Kubuntu. It would not even install Ubuntu. And full installs from flash drives are slow loading, but once in RAM very  fast. With lots of RAM most things are cached into RAM, so drive is less critical. Check top or htop to see if some process is consuming all your resources. Also look at system monitor.